# Join - Left join with a filter on both tables, return zero if no match

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, ssms

I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 values on 2 related tables.

```
    SELECT        a.[Batch No_], b.[Lot No_], b.[Open], a.[Current Stock], b.Amount, a.[Batch Value]
    FROM            [sb] AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     [ile] AS b ON a.[Batch No_] = b.[Lot No_]
    WHERE        (a.[Current Stock] = 1) AND (b.[Open] = 1)
```

I want all records from sb(a) to be returned, where Current Stock = 1.
I want all matching records from ile(b) to be returned, where Open = 1.

The problem is, If there is no matching record, i still want the sb(a) fields to be returned, with b.Amount set to 0.

There are multiple records where b.Open = 0, which must not be returned.

How do I go about this? I saw a solution involving COALESCE, but I couldn't get it working

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you put `WHERE` condition on any column from your `B` table, you are effectively turning your `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER`. You need to move those conditions to the `ON` clause, like shown in answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want A no matter what, do not include any hard conditions on B in your where clause.  All columns of B will be NULL for rows not matched by A.  Move those conditions to your JOIN.  Like this:

```
SELECT        a.[Batch No_], 
              b.[Lot No_], 
              b.[Open], 
              a.[Current Stock], 
              isnull(b.Amount,0) 
              a.[Batch Value]
FROM            [sb] AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                [ile] AS b ON a.[Batch No_] = b.[Lot No_]
                and 1 = b.[Open]
WHERE        (a.[Current Stock] = 1)
```

Then you can use ISNULL or COALESCE in your SELECT clause to force b.amount to be 0 when B is not matched.

Comment: This works perfectly.

Thanks for the explanation, it was most helpful

Answer (score 0):

Put the filtering predicates in the join condition clause.

```
SELECT a.[Batch No_], b.[Lot No_], b.Open, 
     a.[Current Stock], isNull(b.Amount, 0) Amount, 
     a.[Batch Value]
FROM sb a 
  LEFT JOIN ile b 
     ON a.Batch No_ = b.[Lot No_]
        And a.[Current Stock] = 1 
        And b.Open = 1)
```